# mysql datetime select problems

Tags: mysql, datetime, between

I've have problem with mysql select range between two dates.

My query looking at

```
select field_1, date_format(field_date,'%d.%m.%Y') as dt 
from mytable 
where date_format(field_date,'%d.%m.%Y') between '31.10.2019' and 01.11.2019'
```

This query return empty answer. Mytable contains records for 31.10.2019 and earlier, but not contains records after 31.10.2019

field_date is a datetime type

problem is only for ranges after 31.10.2019

Why it not return records when range is out?

Comment: If you want to use betweem I think you have to use a MySQL Date format. `'31.10.2019'` of course is not

Comment: `'%d.%m.%Y'` is not a comparable format.

Comment: You are right, of course. Problem was solved after change format of date to correct. Thank!

Comment: It's all back to front, innit.